Oracle: how to order LISTAGG() list
Oracle 19c
I am trying to write query result into .csv file including column names.
In order to write column names as first line I am planning to loop over the result of this query:
select listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by column_name)
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'NS_INVE_ADJ'
order by column_id

Here are table columns id/name:
1   INVE_AUDIT_EXT_ID
2   TRANS_DATE
3   ADJ_LOCATION
4   ADJUSTMENT_ACCT
5   DIVISION_ID
6   ITEM
7   LOCATIONS
8   PROPERTY_MARK
9   REASON
10  ADJ_QTY
11  DIV_LINE

I noticed that result of the query above sorts it alphabetically, but I need it by column_id.
ADJUSTMENT_ACCT,ADJ_LOCATION,ADJ_QTY,DIVISION_ID,DIV_LINE,INVE_AUDIT_EXT_ID,ITEM,LOCATIONS,PROPERTY_MARK,REASON,TRANS_DATE

What am I missing?
Eugene

Simply sort it by id
select listagg("name",',') within group (order by "id")
from tab




LISTAGG("NAME",',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBY"ID")




INVE_AUDIT_EXT_ID,TRANS_DATE,ADJ_LOCATION,ADJUSTMENT_ACCT,DIVISION_ID,ITEM,LOCATIONS,PROPERTY_MARK,REASON,ADJ_QTY,DIV_LINE



fiddle

Use ORDER BY column_id within the LISTAGG expression:
SELECT LISTAGG(column_name,',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) AS column_names
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'NS_INVE_ADJ'

Which, for the table:
CREATE TABLE NS_INVE_ADJ (
  INVE_AUDIT_EXT_ID NUMBER,
  TRANS_DATE        NUMBER,
  ADJ_LOCATION      NUMBER,
  ADJUSTMENT_ACCT   NUMBER,
  DIVISION_ID       NUMBER,
  ITEM              NUMBER,
  LOCATIONS         NUMBER,
  PROPERTY_MARK     NUMBER,
  REASON            NUMBER,
  ADJ_QTY           NUMBER,
  DIV_LINE          NUMBER
)

Outputs:



COLUMN_NAMES




INVE_AUDIT_EXT_ID,TRANS_DATE,ADJ_LOCATION,ADJUSTMENT_ACCT,DIVISION_ID,ITEM,LOCATIONS,PROPERTY_MARK,REASON,ADJ_QTY,DIV_LINE



fiddle
